# How to expand an image in a table cell on hover (through CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make it so that images in cells in an html table expand when you hover over them. I want this to be universal to all tables on my website. Here's my code so far:

```
td img {
    height: 150px;
}

td img:hover{
    height: 175px;
}
```

This code makes the images appear at their correct height, but nothing hapens when I hover over them. Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but what is it?

Comment: If you suspect there could be an inline style or another selector overriding the height, you could try:
   
    `height: 175px !important;`

Have you tried that?

Comment: Your above CSS looks good here - https://jsfiddle.net/bLc4dyzn/. Your problem must be elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @n8bar I just tried your code, and I still don't have the desired results. Does this help you track down where the problem might be?

Comment: As Tricky12 said, it must be a problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Consider defining the width and height of the cells and adjust the image within those parameters. This way the rows don't shift around when you hover -- [change table image size on hover](https://jsfiddle.net/rt5x3w5b/1/)

```css
html {
    padding: 50px;
}

table {
    width: 600px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #BBB;
}

th {
    padding: 10px;
}

td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
}

td:first-child {
    width: 50px;
}

td:last-child {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

td img {
   width: 75%;
   height: auto;
}

td img:hover{
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Image Title</th>
        <th>Image</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Image 1</td>
            <td><img src="http://www.logoeps.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/stackoverflow_logo.jpg" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

***you can do it with CSS***

```
td:hover img{
 height:175px;
}
```

***you can use jQuery for this also :***

```
$('td img').on('mouseenter',function(){

  $(this).css({
    'height':'175px'
  });

});
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with css op uses, problem is elsewhere :)

Comment: your jQuery needs to be amended to restore the original height on mouse leave.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  height: 150px;
  width: auto
}

td:hover img {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Image</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Image Title</td>
    <td><img src="https://torange.biz/photofx/5/8/image-profile-picture-beautiful-exotic-flower-5532.jpg" alt=""></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```